# Could someone delete noise offensive offtopic comments?

Tags: support, comments, behavior, offensive

There's one angry user who leaves comments with obscene language on my questions https://stackoverflow.com/users/207177?tab=activity#tab-top  (actually, he also downvotes me and some other users as 'for the great justice').

I don't care about downvotes but I don't want to see those comments on my questions especially because it's a public resource which were outstanding among other with its civilized educated community.

So, I think its obviously that those noise should be deleted. I cannot do it myself (at least yet) so I hope someone with correspondent authorities will read this post.

Thanks!

**UPD**: he's amnestied today. And coincidentally I've got 5 downvotes on 5 of my questions without any reasining. Questions are listed below (I've already flagged them):

[What is the correct way of overriding hashCode () and equals () methods of persistent entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928191/what-is-the-correct-way-of-overriding-hashcode-and-equals-methods-of-persis)

[JSF components libs generate awful html-code. It's not OK but is it acceptable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881785/jsf-components-libs-generate-awful-html-code-its-not-ok-but-is-it-acceptable)

[Grouping by 2 fields in XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706412/grouping-by-2-fields-in-xsl)

[Opera handles jQuery's animate method in a very strange way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846334/opera-handles-jquerys-animate-method-in-a-very-strange-way)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328781/unique-nickname-vs-one-nickname-for-many-users

Comment: Oh, *him*. That's not the first time.

Comment: Mods care. Flag your post for mod attention and explain your issue. Then you do not have to wait here, till they find your post.

Comment: He's already suspended.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: I flagged until I got message that 'come into 14 hours' because flags limit exceeded. Could you please explain, how can I 'explain my issue'?

Comment: @Roman it's already in the moderators' hands. The downvotes and comments will be removed, and the user has already been suspended. I don't think there's anything for you to do any more.

Comment: That guy is *mental*. I'm glad I don't share any tags with him.

Comment: @Roman: I think Jeff answered how you can "explain" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it's pretty serious, so I would flag the comments, **and flag the post they are on for moderator attention**.

Like so:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/

[image: moderator flagging]

Comment: oh, I thought 'flag post' was just for the cases when the post itself contained something 'bad'.

Comment: @Roman its a quick way to get mod's attention.  Also, you can leave a little note explaining what's going on; gives us more context.  Hard to tell someone is going mental from just three or four flagged comments.

Comment: What do you do when you run out of flags?